# Modify the location a pointer points to in a C++ function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have gotten stuck on modifying pointers of pointers. The problem is that I don't understand **why my code works**. What I am trying to do is modify where a pointer-to-pointer points to in a function. Then accessing that value in my main function. I tried quite a few attempts and this is the only way I got it to work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void changePP(int **ppint) {
    int *n = new int;
    *n = 9; //just a value for demonstration purposes
    *ppint = n; //THE LINE IN QUESTION
    delete n;
}
int main() {
    int **ppint = NULL;
    int *p = new int;
    *p = 4; //another value for demonstrating
    ppint = &p;
    cout << **ppint << endl;
    changePP(ppint);
    cout << **ppint << endl;
}
```

---

So, the output is 4 and then a 9 on seperate lines. However, I am not sure about the line `*ppint = n` in the code. Why do I have to use the `*` to change where ppint points to in the changePP function but not in the main? Also why do I not have to use the `&` in the function? I can't seem to find an explanation that I can understand on the internet and I was wondering if someone could explain this for me?

Comment: `ppint = &p` ppint now points to p. `*ppint = n` the pointer pointed TO by ppint now points to the same thing that n points to.

Comment: The only way to answer this question is to explain to you how pointers work and to step you through your code, all of which is off-topic for never being able to help anyone else. It's too localised!

Comment: Let's ignore the detail of the undefined behaviour of where a deleted pointer is later dereferenced.  Note that n gets a new int, that n gets assigned to `*ppint` (the one in changePP, which results in `*ppint` in main changing as well... perhaps a different name would have been wiser), and is then deleted.  Back in main, `ppint` gets dereferenced twice, the second one attempting to follow an already deleted pointer.  Game Over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: these memory addresses are only for illustration.

#### Memory Layout

```
0x0A | 4
0x0B | 'p' -> 0x0A // Pointer to the value 4 in location 0x0A
0x0C | 'ppint' -> NULL // Initially a null pointer
```

Performing `ppint = &p;` produces the following because here `ppint` is the pointer located at `0x0C`.

```
0x0A | 4
0x0B | 'p' -> 0x0A
0x0C | 'ppint' -> 0x0B
```

As for the parameter in the `changePP` function, I will refer to it as `ppintCopy` for less confusion. It's a copy (i.e., a pointer different than `ppint`) and modifying it only modifies the copy.

```
0x0D | 'ppintCopy' -> 0x0C // A pointer that points to `ppint`
```

Performing `ppintCopy = &n` would modify the pointer at `0x0D` which is not the location of the pointer from the `main` function. **However**, deferencing `ppintCopy` (i.e., `*ppintCopy`) yields `0X0C` which is the pointer from the `main` function therefore `*ppintCopy = n;` is changing where the pointer `0x0C` points.

> Why do I have to use the * to change where ppint points to in the changePP function but not in the main?

With the above illustration I hope it is more clear why it works in `main` and why you have to use a different syntax in the `changePP` function.

> Also why do I not have to use the & in the function?

In the `main` function the variable `ppint` is of type `int**` (i.e., a pointer to a pointer) and `p` is of type `int*`. You cannot perform `ppint = p;` because the they are different types. This may be easier to see if you remove one level of indirection. For example:

```
int* pMyInt = NULL;
int myInt = 3;
```

I think it's pretty self explanatory that this cannot work (i.e., they are different types).

```
pMyInt = myInt;
```

However you can take the address of `myInt` using the `&` operator which results in a pointer to int (i.e., `int*`) and since this type is the same as the type of `pMyInt` the assignment is now possible.

```
pMyInt = &myInt;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ppint; // the variable name
*ppint; // dereference the first layer of pointer
*(*ppint);  // dereference the first layer of pointer which points to another pointer that contains a **value**
```

Thus `*ppint = n;` means **point `ppint` to another memory location** which is the location assigned to `n` or it could be rewritten as `*ppint = &n;`

After that line, you have deleted the `n` but you didn't change its value so the value remains unchanged unless something have accessed and modified it.

The reason why you still retain the value of `n` after deleting it is considered as undefined behaviour though.

Comment: Well done for spotting the undefined behavior, I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are already messy to deal with, you didn't have to make it worse. This works as well:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void changePP(int *ppint) {
    *ppint = 9;
}
int main() {
    int p = 4;
    int *ppint = &p;
    cout << *ppint << endl; // this could be replaced with /*p*/
    changePP(ppint); // note you could have replaced this parameter with /*&p*/
    cout << *ppint << endl; // this could be replaced with /*p*/
}
```

Let me try to explain what your code is doing, but please for future, don't ever do it this way. Do it the way I've shown

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void changePP(int **ppint) {
    int *n = new int; // you allocate memory for a single integer (again it is uninitialised)
    *n = 9; // the value at the above pointer is now changed to 9
    *ppint = n; // here you have just dereferenced a pointer to pointer which gives you a pointer, so in essence you are changing the location in memory where this pointer is pointing and it is now pointing to whatever memory address n was
    delete n;
}
int main() {
    int **ppint = NULL; // Here you have declared a pointer to pointer which is NULL
    int *p = new int; // You can do better here with /*new int(4)*/
    *p = 4; // this changes the value that p initially held (which could be anything)
    ppint = &p; // reference to a pointer always creates a pointer to a pointer and since that is what ppint is, you are safe here
    cout << **ppint << endl; // print the value nested within this pointer
    changePP(ppint); // now you call the function with a variable of type pointer to pointer. Note you could have passed &p as parameter here and it would have still worked
    cout << **ppint << endl;
}
```

What is the moral of the story?

When passing a parameter `v` to a function,

- `&v` will produce a pointer to v
- `*v` will dereference v and will give you access to whatever `v` was pointing to

When `v` is a parameter in a function,

- `&v` will bring the actual object `v` into the scope of the function. This is called pass by reference
- `*v` Is a pointer to v, and this is <s>still pass by reference</s> called pass by value because you are passing a pointer(Thanks Kirk)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. It's clearly a learning exercise and not an attempt to write pristine code.

Comment: I know this, but this is better than having to explain to OP that his code is leaking memory (which opens up another can of worms), and the internals of pointer to pointer

Comment: The OP wants to be explained the internals of pointer to pointer.

Comment: `*n = 9; // the value of the above pointer is now changed to 9` It's the value of the integer that is changed, not the pointer.

Comment: `*v Is a pointer to v, and this is still pass by reference` It's not pass by reference. The pointer is passed by value.