# changing the location a pointer-to-pointer points to while maintaining the value of two other pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

So, I have been trying to learn C++ and in the tutorial book that I am reading, I have gotten stuck on a problem of pointers-to-pointers. What I am trying to do change the pointer a pointer-to-pointer is pointing to without changing the value of the original pointer. Here's some code...

```
#include <iostream>
void testFunc(int **func_p_to_p) {
    int *createdPointer = new int(10);
    *func_p_to_p = createdPointer;
    cout << **func_p_to_p << endl; //prints 10 as I expect
}
int main() {
    int **main_p_to_p = NULL;
    int *mainPointer = new int(5);
    main_p_to_p = &mainPointer;
    testFunc(main_p_to_p);
    cout << **test << endl;//prints 10, I expect this...
    cout << *mainPointer << endl; //prints 10 as well, I don't want that.
}
```

I asked a similar question about this earlier, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910673/modify-the-location-a-pointer-points-to-in-a-c-function) and I understand sort of what is going on. However, I can't seem to figure out how I would change where a pointer-to-pointer is pointing to without changing the original value. Could anyone explain how I would do this? Thanks.

Comment: You need `int *mainPointer = new int[5];` if using `new` at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no he doesn't. `new int(5)` allocates a single `int` initialised to 5.

Comment: @immibis And how does this make the code working as expected?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the OP seems to be *expecting* to allocate an int initialized to 5 - which is what his code does do - not an array of 5 ints.

Comment: @immibis Actually it seems to be completely unclear what the OP want's to achieve with these weird pointer references and `new` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
*func_p_to_p = createdPointer;
```

you first follow your pointer-pointer to what it is pointing to: The address of `int *mainPointer`.

Next you assign a new value to this pointer, the value of `createdPointer` which is the address of `new int(10)`.

So your mainPointer is now changed to target the same memory as createdPointer. Does this make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. `main_p_to_p` points to `mainPointer`, so modifying `*main_p_to_p` modifies `mainPointer`, full stop.

You might be looking for this, though:

```
int main() {
    int **main_p_to_p = NULL;
    int *mainPointer = new int(5);
    int *secondPointer = mainPointer;

    main_p_to_p = &secondPointer;

    // prints 5 5 5
    cout << *mainPointer << " " << *secondPointer << " " << **main_p_to_p << std::endl;

    testFunc(main_p_to_p);

    // prints 5 10 10
    cout << *mainPointer << " " << *secondPointer << " " << **main_p_to_p << std::endl;
}
```

Note that you don't need the `main_p_to_p` variable, but I left it in for consistency with the question.